# Strange string split behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I run

```
'{{123}}'.split(/(\{\{)|(\}\})/g, -1)
```

I expect

```
["", "123", ""]
```

But it shows

```
["", "{{", undefined, "123", undefined, "}}", ""]
```

Why?? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Why have you passed a negative limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
'{{123}}'.split(/\{\{|\}\}/)
```

You don't need to catch group when using `.split`

Comment: You don't need the global flag, and `-1` as a limit is not very useful either I think.

Answer (score 1):

http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.14

If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. For example,

```
"A<B>bold</B>and<CODE>coded</CODE>".split(/<(\/)?([^<>]+)>/)
```

evaluates to the array

```
["A", undefined, "B", "bold", "/", "B", "and", undefined, "CODE", "coded", "/", "CODE", ""]
```

So, `'{{123}}'.split(/(\{\{)|(\}\})/g, -1)` returns

```
["",
"{{", undefined, // "{{" is matched, but "}}" isn't.
"123",
undefined, "}}", // "{{" isn't matched, but "}}" is matched. 
""]
```